# Cypress test seems to 'ignore' mat-paginator pageSize

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I am trying to solve a bug in an integration test, which should test if switching between pages using mat-paginator is working correctly. The paginator has a pageSize of 20, the response fixture contains 24 'items'. I expect to see 20 table rows, an enabled 'next' button and the remaining 4 rows when I click on that button. It works fine in the application, but when I run the test, it seems as if the pageSize is ignored. The 'next' button is disabled, the paginator says 'Page 1 of 1' and all 24 items are shown.

The error I get is `Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is disabled`, which makes sense because there's only one page instead of two.

I tried different things such as changing the amount of items and changing the pageSize in both the actual code of the application and inspecting the element in the test window (using Chrome 84). Also moving `"items"` into `"data"` did not work.

These are the test, manyItems and the paginator (I did remove some code that doesn't apply to this problem)

**Test**

```
cy.route({ method: 'POST', url: '**/graphql', response: manyItems }).as('manyItems');
cy.visit('/items');
cy.wait(['@manyItems', '@uset', '@colleagues', '@groups'], { requestTimeout: 10000 });
cy.get('.mat-paginator').find('button.mat-paginator-navigation-next.mat-icon-button').click();
```

**manyItems**

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      { },
      { }, // etc.
    ]
  }
}
```

**Paginator**

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="20" [hidePageSize]="true" *ngIf="dataSource.data.length > 0"></mat-paginator>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit**

The dataSource paginator gets set with a timeout around it:

```
setTimeout(() => (this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator));
```

Now when I remove the timeout, the paginator doesn't work in the actual application, so I'm thinking this issue *might* have to do something with it?

Comment: You try to assert on a DOM element based on API response which is not necessarily wrong, but it might take some time in order to render. Could you add a `cy.reload()` before `cy.get('.mat-paginator') ... ` and run it again? Let's make sure is not about the component state.

Comment: Reloading didn't work, it still loads all 24 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the setTimout was actually causing the issue! The way I fixed it is by simply adding `cy.tick(1000)` after the wait:

```
cy.route({ method: 'POST', url: '**/graphql', response: manyItems }).as('manyItems');
cy.visit('/items');
cy.wait(['@manyItems', '@uset', '@colleagues', '@groups'], { requestTimeout: 10000 });
cy.tick(1000);
cy.get('.mat-paginator').find('button.mat-paginator-navigation-next.mat-icon-button').click();
```

Thanks again for all the comments!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a settling problem as @AlexIzbas suggests, you could preceed the button click with a test of the range label,

```js
cy.route({ method: 'POST', url: '**/graphql', response: manyItems }).as('manyItems');
cy.visit('/items');
cy.wait(['@manyItems'], { requestTimeout: 10000 });

cy.get('.mat-paginator')
  .find('.mat-paginator-range-label')
  .should('contain', `20 of ${dataSource.length}`);

cy.get('.mat-paginator')
  .find('button.mat-paginator-next')
  .click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the range label check, however, it should say "Page 1 of 2" (it still says 1 of 1).
I do want to try and check the dataSource, but how do I access it from here? It says it is undefined. I tried importing the component and the variable itself but no success (I'm quite new to Cypress).

Comment: Ok, that rules out lag in the loading - in any case your handling of the route looks good (I presume you preceed `cy.route()` with `cy.server()` which is a requirement).

Comment: I tried a test on [https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples) and it works ok. One thing the examples use `pageSizeOptions` attribute, does it improve if you set this?

Comment: `cy.server()` gets executed before each test. Sadly adding `pageSizeOptions` did not solve the issue either. Now we have some other pages that use a paginator, most of them have a page size of 20 too and are implemented the exact same way, those tests do work. Could `manyItems` be causing the problem?

Comment: Your ng-if directive should be `*ngIf="dataSource.data.length > 0"` if you are using the latest version angular-material. I can't correlate your problem description to what I observed, but console logging dataSource in `ngAfterViewInit()`, I can see there's no length property on datasource, but datasource.data has one. BTW I suppose you have `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` in ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: I haven't built angular material app for a while now, must say it's an horrendous experience to get it going.

Comment: I completely forgot to include `.data` in this example, we do use it in the actual code (oops). `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator` gets set in `ngAfterViewInit()`. I will include the structure of `manyItems` in the question, maybe something is wrong in there.

Comment: [This](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxxpqbqolyb?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts) is the example I used to test (data is hard-coded). Can't run Cypress against the online page, it gets stuck on the compilation, but exporting and running on localhost it pages correctly and next button click works.